# How to improve my code which removes a row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I start with test.csv which contains:

```
Name,Date,Weight
Jonny,03-08-2019,100
Sally,03-08-2019,120
Bobby,03-08-2019,200
```

Using `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=None, header='infer')` I load test.csv into a DataFrame which produces:

```
    Name        Date  Weight
0  Jonny  03-08-2019     100
1  Sally  03-08-2019     120
2  Bobby  03-08-2019     200
```

I then created a function to delete a row chosen by the user. But I'm doing it by splitting the DataFrame at the chosen row and then appending the 2 DataFrames back together. Is there an easier way to do this? I looked at df.drop() but couldn't drop the whole row.

```
def delete_entry(df):
    num_to_delete = int(input("Delete which row? "))

    first_rows_to_keep = df.iloc[:num_to_delete]
    last_rows_to_keep = df.iloc[num_to_delete+1:]
    new_df = first_rows_to_keep.append(last_rows_to_keep)
    with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
        new_df.to_csv(f, index=False)
```

Looking for ways to improve my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you use the [`.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method of the pandas df, using appropriate arguments to drop specified rows in place.

For example, to drop a given row:

```
df.drop(num_to_delete, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

where the second argument ('axis') denotes the dropping of rows (as opposed to columns) and the final argument specifies the operation to be performed in place.

You could also consider looking at the `.set_index` method. This would, for example, give you the ability to drop rows depending on the value of a given column (i.e., drop everyone with the name Bobby).

Comment: No problem, you could also look at .set_index() method. This would enable easy dropping of rows with certain values.

Answer (score 1):

In your case index based dropping of columns makes most sense.

```
df.drop(df.index[2])
```

This will remove the third row, containing the data about Bobby.

Comment: This causes an `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`

Comment: I see. Yes this happened because you are inferring your headers. My bad, please try with `df.drop(df.index[1])`